# how to get priamry key in return after inserting the row in table with liferay custom MVC portlet?

Tags: liferay, primary-key, portlet, liferay-6

I am developing one custom portlet with mvc in eclipse IDE.

Following is my scenario:

I have one table name as `restaurant` and from `addrestaurant.jsp` page I am adding the data in restaurant table.

In my `addrestaurant.jsp` page I have following code of select control which takes multiple value to be selected:

```html
<label>Select Ad Type<span class="f_req">*</span></label>                                                
<select data-placeholder="- Select Ad Type -" class="chzn-select" multiple name="ad_type" value="<%=restaurantOBJ.getAdtypeId()%>">
    <option value="1">Standby Ad</option>
    <option value="2">Homepage Ad</option>
    <option value="3">Slider Ad</option>
    <option value="4">Event Based Ad</option>
</select>
```

Now this `adtype` selected from `addrestaurant.jsp` will be inserted in one `rest_map_adtype` table,
where I want to add these selected value with the reference of restaurant primary-key which is just created last.

So how can I get the primary key of `restaurant` which is last edited

For more explanation let me give some code snippet:

```java
public void addRestaurant(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

    log.info("Inside addRegistration");
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    restaurant rest = RestaurantActionUtil
            .getRestaurantFromRequest(request);     

    boolean restValid = RestaurantValidator
            .validateRestaurant(rest, errors);

    if (restValid) {
        try {
            log.info(rest);

            restaurant test = restaurantLocalServiceUtil
                    .addrestaurant(rest);

        //Above Code will add the all data which is in my addrestaurant.jsp accept just selected control values

            String[] adtype_ID=request.getParameterValues("ad_Type");

            //here am taking the select tag's multiple value in one string array
```

So after this line I need to add all the values in `rest_map_Adtype` table with the reference of restaurant primary key which is just created with the `addrestaurant(rest)` method just a line above.

How can I make it possible?

or how can I get the primary key in return after inserting the row in table?

My ActionUtil.class follows

```java
public restaurant addRestaurant(restaurant restParam) {
        restaurant restVar;

        try {



            restVar = restaurantPersistence.create(counterLocalService
                    .increment(restaurant.class.toString()));
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }

        try {



            resourceLocalService.addResources(restParam.getGroupId(),restParam.getGroupId(), restParam.getUserId(),
                    restaurant.class.getName(),restParam.getPrimaryKey(), false,true,true);
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }

        restVar.setName(restParam.getName());
        restVar.setAdress(restParam.getAdress());
        restVar.setCity(restParam.getCity());
        restVar.setPin(restParam.getPin());
        restVar.setState(restParam.getState());
        restVar.setCountry(restParam.getCountry());
        restVar.setContactno(restParam.getContactno());
        restVar.setEmail(restParam.getEmail());
        restVar.setWebsite(restParam.getWebsite());
        restVar.setCuisinetype(restParam.getCuisinetype());
        restVar.setPersonalmail(restParam.getPersonalmail());
        restVar.setPersonalname(restParam.getPersonalname());
        restVar.setPersonalPhone(restParam.getPersonalPhone());
        restVar.setNoofemenuagent(restParam.getNoofemenuagent());
        restVar.setLicensekey(restParam.getLicensekey());
        restVar.setRestregId(restParam.getRestregId());
        restVar.setNoofdiningtable(restParam.getNoofdiningtable());
        restVar.setAvgnoofcustomermonthly(restParam.getAvgnoofcustomermonthly());
        restVar.setAveragroupagevisit(restParam.getAveragroupagevisit());
        restVar.setImpoflocation(restParam.getImpoflocation());
        restVar.setAvgmonthlycheckamount(restParam.getAvgmonthlycheckamount());
        restVar.setCostperthousandimpression(restParam.getCostperthousandimpression());
        restVar.setAdtypeId(restParam.getAdtypeId());
        //restVar.setNoofdiningtable(restParam.getNoofdiningtable());
        //restVar.setAvgnoofcustomermonthly(restParam.getAvgnoofcustomermonthly());


        restVar.setIsactive(restParam.getIsactive());
        restVar.setCreateddate(restParam.getCreateddate());
        restVar.setLastmodifiedby(restParam.getLastmodifiedby());
        restVar.setModifieddate(restParam.getModifieddate());
        restVar.setGroupId(restParam.getGroupId());
        restVar.setUserId(restParam.getUserId());
        restVar.setIsdeleted(restParam.getIsdeleted());
        restVar.setRestregId(restParam.getRestregId());

        //restVar.setOrganizationId(restParam.getOrganizationId());

        try {
            return restaurantPersistence.update(restVar, false);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }
    }
```

following is my object restaurant which returns following value after add restaurant      `{restId=0, name=aaaa, isactive=false, userId=10158, groupId=10180, createddate=Fri Oct 26 12:40:53 GMT 2012, lastmodifiedby=10158, modifieddate=Fri Oct 26 12:40:53 GMT 2012, restregId=12333, adress=, city=AHMEDABAD, pin=, state=, country=, contactno=, email=, website=, cuisinetype=, noofemenuagent=0, personalname=, personalPhone=, personalmail=, adtypeId=0, isdeleted=false, licensekey=12333, noofdiningtable=0, averagroupagevisit=0, impoflocation=, avgnoofcustomermonthly=0, avgmonthlycheckamount=0, costperthousandimpression=0.0}`

restaurantLocalServiceUtil Class

```java
public static emenu.advertise.database.model.restaurant addrestaurant(
        emenu.advertise.database.model.restaurant restaurant)
        throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
        return getService().addrestaurant(restaurant);
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new restaurant with the primary key. Does not add the restaurant to the database.
    *
    * @param restId the primary key for the new restaurant
    * @return the new restaurant
    */
    public static emenu.advertise.database.model.restaurant createrestaurant(
        long restId) {
        return getService().createrestaurant(restId);
    }
```

Comment: What is written inside this method `restaurantLocalServiceUtil.addrestaurant(rest);`?

Comment: please see my updated question for that.

Answer (score 2):

This statement sets the primary key in your `restVar` i.e. `restaurant` object:

```java
restVar = restaurantPersistence.create(counterLocalService
                .increment(restaurant.class.toString()));
```

And when you do this:

```java
return restaurantPersistence.update(restVar, false);
```

It actually returns the `restaurant` object which should contain the generated primary-key.

So after the following call:

```java
restaurant test = restaurantLocalServiceUtil.addrestaurant(rest);
```

you can simply do:

```java
long restId = test.getPrimaryKey(); // this would return the primary-key
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya,.,,i had done same way..but dont know some how the restaurant object generated its getting rest_ID =0 and thats why getttin error.please refer my question for that

Comment: did you do a `restaurent.getPrimaryKey();` or `restaurant.getRestId()` ?

Comment: am giving u my restaurantlocalserviceUtil class also at the end of my question.please see if any mistake ther.

Comment: `restaurantLocalServiceUtil` class is auto-generated by liferay. So no need for this.